# Using checkboxes inside my ag-grid with boolean fields behind and check/uncheck only with the keyboard

Tags: ag-grid

I have some **boolean** fields inside my `ag-grid`. In addition to be possible to navigate with the keyboard, I would also like to be possible to check/uncheck these checkboxes with the keyboard. I mean let the user move inside the grid with cursor keys, then when the current cell is a checkbox simply use the `Space` of `Enter` keys to check/uncheck.

I ended with the solution showed below but I am curious if there is a better/nicer solution for that ?

The trick I used is to catch keyboard events on the grid and change values (true/false) if focused cell is a checkbox.

Example: [Plunker demo here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/UgKUkkkOcL1Wm3H6)

[image]

```js
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", width: 150, editable: true},
    {headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 60, editable: true},
    {headerName: "Country", field: "country", width: 120, editable: true},
    {headerName: "Boo1", field: "boo1", width: 60, cellRenderer: boolRenderer},
    {headerName: "Boo2", field: "boo2", width: 60, cellRenderer: boolRenderer} 
];

function boolRenderer(params) {
    return `<input type="checkbox" ${params.value ? 'checked' : ''} />`;
}

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    onCellKeyPress: cellKeyPress
}; 

function cellKeyPress(e) {
  
    let ENTER_KEY = 13;
    let SPACE_KEY = 32;

    var event = e.event;

    if (event.keyCode == SPACE_KEY || event.keyCode == ENTER_KEY) 
    {    
        var isCheckbox = $(event.target).find("input[type='checkbox']").length > 0;
        if (isCheckbox) 
        {
            var currentCell = gridOptions.api.getFocusedCell();
            var rowIndex = currentCell.rowIndex;
            var colId = currentCell.column.getId();
            var rowNode = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);
            var cellValue = gridOptions.api.getValue(colId, rowNode) || false;
            rowNode.setDataValue(colId, !cellValue);
        }
    }
}

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    // do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep the example self contained.
    // you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else to do your HTTP calls.
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json');
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(httpResult);
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.test-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script> var __basePath = ''; </script>
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    html {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 1rem;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@21.2.0/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="test-container">

    <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-balham" style="height: calc(100% - 30px);"></div>
</div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your demo, clicking the checkboxes doesn't update the underlying value. Have you already handled that case in your real code?

Comment: I guess you tested with something else that Google Chrome ? You are right: there was a bug when testing with (for example) Microsoft Edge. It works now. I updated the code above. The bug was occurred when using the keyboard for checking/unchecking. The keyCode was differently managed between GC and Edge. My initial question is still : "is there a better/nicer solution for that ?"

Comment: No, I was using Chrome. What I meant is: real users will also sometimes click the checkboxes, and nothing in your current code (even your updated code) handles this case. You would usually not want to bind different events for keypress/click, but instead have one central function. Therefore, I was asking if you already have code to handle mouse click events. This is part of finding a nicer solution.

Comment: Well, maybe you never used the `Aurelia` framework. Each column in the `columnDefs` is **bound** to a `field`. So whenever you click on a checkbox, Aurelia is smart enough to change the value of field behind. The only thing that was not automatically managed (by Aurelia) was the key handling that's why I had to do it manually. At the same time, I updated my code again to have a more generic solution but still want to know if somebody have a better solution.

Comment: Looking here: https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/checkboxes#booleans. That demo already works with both clicking and keyboard navigation. Maybe you're not using the same type of binding? Or if you are, maybe you want to trigger some Aurelia event instead of "manually" setting it with `.setDataValue`? I wouldn't worry about this too much though, it looks like you already have a decent solution. If you do want a better solution, it might have been useful to include that you're using Aurelia in the first place. But then maybe you would get no feedback, since it's not too popular. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

if you asking about alternative way , this is my suggestion .

you can try agSelectCellEditor in the columnDefs , user will still be able to change it using keyboard by pressing enter and select true or false using arrow key.

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'ID',
    field: 'id',
    width: 50
  },
    headerName: 'IsCompleted',
    field: 'isCompleted',
    editable: true,
    filter: true,
    sortable: true,
    cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
    cellEditorParams:
      {
        values: ["True", "False"]
      },
    width: 105}
   ]
```

And to save your changes on the server side:

```
(cellEditingStopped)="UpdateTrainingData()" //as an example your ag-grid html tag.
```

Comment: I would like to use checkboxes and not select lists. Thanks anyway.